# Sparse linear discriminant analysis for regression problem?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, latent-dirichlet-allocation

So far, Linear Discriminant Analysis has beed used for classification problems http://proceedings.mlr.press/v38/wu15.pdf . I wonder if there are any ways to adapt it to regression problems?